# Código não lê o ELSE

Tags: java, android, condição

Fala pessoal, sou iniciante no Android e gostaria que voces me tirassem uma dúvida.
Estou fazendo um app para que o usuário complete todos os EditText's para que o programa possa realizar os devidos cálculos e portanto expor o resultado na Activity seguinte, que seria chamada. Depois do cod verificar os EditText's, ele deveria entrar no ELSE para poder abrir a nova janela, porém isso não ocorre. As mensagens de alertas das verificações são mostradas normalmente, mas a parte de ir pra outra tela não o é.
Voces sabem o que pode ser?
A seguir o código, ele é um pouco grande mas não é difícil e eu imagino que muitos de voces não irão ve-lo por completo, mas vamos lá:

```
  public void onClick (View View) {

    // RESISTENCIA DO CONCRETO

    if (txt_resistencia_concreto.getText().toString().equals("")) {   // O que faltava era o toString()

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha a resistência do concreto");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();


        //MASSA ESPECIFICA DO CIMENTO

    } else if (txt_massa_especifica_cimento.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha a massa específica do cimento");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //ADITIVO MINERAL - VERIFICAÇÃO 1

        //TODOS OS CAMPOS VAZIOS
    } else if (txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral1.getText().toString().equals("") && txt_teor_aditivo_mineral1.getText().toString().equals("") && txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral2.getText().toString().equals("") && txt_teor_aditivo_mineral2.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha ao menos um aditivo mineral.");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //ADITIVO MINERAL - VERIFICAÇÃO 2

        //MASSA ESPECIFICA DO ADITIVO MINERAL 1 VAZIA E TEOR PREENCHIDO
    } else if (txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral1.getText().toString().equals("") && (txt_teor_aditivo_mineral1.length() != 0)) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha o teor de aditivo mineral 1.");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //ADITIVO MINERAL - VERIFICAÇÃO 3

        //MASSA ESPECIFICA DO ADITIVO MINERAL 1 PREENCHIDA E TEOR VAZIO
    } else if (txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral1.length() != 0 && (txt_teor_aditivo_mineral1.getText().toString().equals(""))) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha o teor a ser utilizado do aditivo mineral 1.");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //ADITIVO MINERAL - VERIFICAÇÃO 4

        //MASSA ESPECIFICA DO ADITIVO MINERAL 2 VAZIA E TEOR PREENCHIDO
    } else if (txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral2.getText().toString().equals("") && (txt_teor_aditivo_mineral2.length() != 0)) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha o teor de aditivo mineral 2.");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //ADITIVO MINERAL - VERIFICAÇÃO 5

        //MASSA ESPECIFICA DO ADITIVO MINERAL 2 PREENCHIDA E TEOR VAZIO
    } else if (txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral2.length() != 0 && (txt_teor_aditivo_mineral2.getText().toString().equals(""))) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha a massa específica do aditivo mineral 1.");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //MASSA ESPECIFICA SSS DA BRITA

    } else if (txt_massa_especifica_sss_brita.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha a massa especifica sss da brita");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //TEOR AGUA NA BRITA

    } else if (txt_teor_agua_brita.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha o teor de água que consta na brita");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //ABSORCAO AGUA NA BRITA

    } else if (txt_absorcao_agua_brita.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha a absorção de água da brita");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();


        //MASSA ESPECIFICA SSS NA AREIA

    } else if (txt_massa_especifica_sss_areia.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha a massa especifica SSS da areia");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //TEOR ÁGUA NA AREIA

    } else if (txt_teor_agua_areia.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha o teor de água que consta na areia");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //ABSORCAO AGUA NA AREIA

    } else if (txt_absorcao_agua_areia.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha a absorção de água da areia");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //MASSA ESPECIFICA ADITIVO

    } else if (txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_quimico.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha a massa especifica do aditivo quimico");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //PONTO SATURACAO ADITIVO

    } else if (txt_ponto_Saturacao.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha o ponto de saturação do aditivo quimico");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //TEOR DE SOLIDOS

    } else if (txt_teor_solidos.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha o teor de sólidos do aditivo químico");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //AR INCORPORADO

    } else if (txt_ar_incorporado.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha o teor de ar incorporado no concreto");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();


        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        //SE O MÉTODO DE AITCIN FOI SELECIONADO, VERIFICA SE A RESISTENCIA ESTÁ DENTRO DOS LIMITES

    } else if (check_aitcin.isChecked()) {

        double converte_resistencia = Double.parseDouble(txt_resistencia_concreto.getText().toString());

        if (converte_resistencia < 40 || converte_resistencia > 160) {

            //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            //define o titulo

            builder.setTitle("Resistência do Concreto");

            //define a mensagem
            builder.setMessage("O método de Aitcin é limitado para resistencias entre 40 e 160 MPA.");

            //define um botão como positivo
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }


        //SE O MÉTODO DE MEHTA FOI SELECIONADO, VERIFICA SE A RESISTENCIA ESTÁ DENTRO DOS LIMITES

    } else if (check_mehta.isChecked()) {

        double converte_resistencia = Double.parseDouble(txt_resistencia_concreto.getText().toString());

        if (converte_resistencia < 60 || converte_resistencia > 120) {

            //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            //define o titulo

            builder.setTitle("Resistência do Concreto");

            //define a mensagem
            builder.setMessage("O método de Mehta - Aitcin é limitado para resistencias entre 60 e 120 MPA. ");

            //define um botão como positivo
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }

        //TEOR DE ADITIVO QUIMICO

    } else if (check_mehta.isChecked() && txt_teor_aditivo.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("Preencha o teor de aditivo químico");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        //SE METODO DE AITCIN FOI SELECIONADO,

    } else {

       Intent it = new Intent (this, Resultado_Aitcin.class);

        startActivity(it);

    }

}
```

Comment: Ana, se o `Intent` deve ser sempre criado, (citado em: "Depois do cod verificar os EditText's, ele deveria entrar no ELSE"), então o else não deveria existir, seria só colocar o que está dentro do else no final do método. Pois quando uma dessas condições do `if` ou ìf else` são verdadeiras, as demais não não nem verificadas. Acho que é esse o problema

Comment: Bem, fiz exatamente o que voce sugeriu e o app simplesmente fecha. Ainda, está desconsiderando que o usuário vai insistir no erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void onClick (View View) {

// RESISTENCIA DO CONCRETO

    if (txt_resistencia_concreto.getText().toString().equals("")) // O que faltava era o toString()
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a resistência do concreto");

    else if (txt_massa_especifica_cimento.getText().toString().equals("")) 
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a massa específica do cimento");

    else if (txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral1.getText().toString().equals("") && txt_teor_aditivo_mineral1.getText().toString().equals("") && txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral2.getText().toString().equals("") && txt_teor_aditivo_mineral2.getText().toString().equals("")) 
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha ao menos um aditivo mineral.");

    else if (txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral1.getText().toString().equals("") && (txt_teor_aditivo_mineral1.length() != 0)) 
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha o teor de aditivo mineral 1.");

    else if (txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral1.length() != 0 && (txt_teor_aditivo_mineral1.getText().toString().equals(""))) 
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha o teor de aditivo mineral 2.");

    else if (txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral2.getText().toString().equals("") && (txt_teor_aditivo_mineral2.length() != 0)) 
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha o teor de aditivo mineral 2.");

    else if (txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral2.length() != 0 && (txt_teor_aditivo_mineral2.getText().toString().equals("")))
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a massa específica do aditivo mineral 1.");

    else if (txt_massa_especifica_sss_brita.getText().toString().equals("")) 
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a massa especifica sss da brita");

    else if (txt_teor_agua_brita.getText().toString().equals("")) 
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha o teor de água que consta na brita");

    else if (txt_absorcao_agua_brita.getText().toString().equals("")) 
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a absorção de água da brita");

    else if (txt_massa_especifica_sss_areia.getText().toString().equals("")) 
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a massa especifica SSS da areia");

    else if (txt_teor_agua_areia.getText().toString().equals("")) 
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha o teor de água que consta na areia");

    else if (txt_absorcao_agua_areia.getText().toString().equals("")) 
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a absorção de água da areia");

    else if (txt_massa_especifica_aditivo_quimico.getText().toString().equals(""))
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a massa especifica do aditivo quimico");

    else if (txt_ponto_Saturacao.getText().toString().equals(""))   
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha o ponto de saturação do aditivo quimico");

    else if (txt_teor_solidos.getText().toString().equals(""))      
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha o teor de sólidos de aditivos quimicos");

    else if (txt_ar_incorporado.getText().toString().equals(""))    
        showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha o teor de ar incorporado no concreto");

    else {
        if (check_aitcin.isChecked()) {
            double converte_resistencia =  Double.parseDouble(txt_resistencia_concreto.getText().toString());
            if (converte_resistencia < 40 || converte_resistencia > 160) {

            }
        } else if (check_mehta.isChecked()) {
            double converte_resistencia =  Double.parseDouble(txt_resistencia_concreto.getText().toString());
            if (converte_resistencia < 60 || converte_resistencia > 120) {

            }
        }
       startActivity(new Intent(this, Resultado_Aitcin.class));
    }

}

private void showError(String title, String err){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(err);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Refiz o seu **código** e acredito que o problema tenha sido resolvido, também removi algumas coisas desnecessárias e que poderiam ser reutilizadas. O **código** parece-me mais limpo.

Pelo o que vi, o problema parecia estar nesse trecho de código:

```
else if (check_mehta.isChecked()) {

    double converte_resistencia = Double.parseDouble(txt_resistencia_concreto.getText().toString());

    if (converte_resistencia < 60 || converte_resistencia > 120) {

        //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //define o titulo

        builder.setTitle("Resistência do Concreto");

        //define a mensagem
        builder.setMessage("O método de Mehta - Aitcin é limitado para resistencias entre 60 e 120 MPA. ");

        //define um botão como positivo
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

    //TEOR DE ADITIVO QUIMICO

} else if (check_mehta.isChecked() && txt_teor_aditivo.getText().toString().equals("")) {

    //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    //define o titulo

    builder.setTitle("Campos em branco");

    //define a mensagem
    builder.setMessage("Preencha o teor de aditivo químico");

    //define um botão como positivo
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

    //SE METODO DE AITCIN FOI SELECIONADO,

} else {

   Intent it = new Intent (this, Resultado_Aitcin.class);

    startActivity(it);

}
```

Veja que no seu código acima você criou uma condição para que SE um dos seus `checkbox` estiverem sido marcados, ele re-analisa a condição e verifica se um valor em específico foi inserido. Eu movi essa verificação para o `else`, pois só vai entrar no `else` se todas as `EditText` forem preenchidas, ou seja, não precisa verificar se há alguma em branco novamente, oque foi feito por você, e então, **se nada estiver em branco**, executa uma ação, **mas isso não foi feito**, por isso não chega no `ELSE`.

Comment: Cara!!!! Muito obrigada!!!!! Funcionou!!!!! Muito obrigada de verdade!!!!! Eu já estava neurótica com isso!!!

Comment: Bom ter ajudado! :)